# How to add Google analytics to link tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-analytics

I have this site done in [WordPress Visual composer](http://wordpressdev.burnnotice.co.za/) and the site has Google Analytics. However, I would like to specifically add analytics to specific links of the header so that I can track how many clicks were on the same links. The links  are contact number and the email.

Here are the links I want to add:

```
<a href="tel:0110392630" target="_blank">011 039 2630</a>  |  <a href="tel:0720660989" target="_blank">072 066 0989</a>
<a href="mailto:info@taxleaders.net">info@taxleaders.net</a>
```

How can add analytics to those links using javascript/jquery?

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to outbound the link to track via GA,

/**
* Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
* using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
*/

```
<script>
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
```

You'll also need to add (or modify) the onclick attribute to your links. Use this example as a model for your own links:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

Reference : [GA](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en)

Comment: Will add that to my js now.

Comment: nice. let me know the results also.

Comment: So I made it like this for my site:<a href="mailto:info@taxleaders.net" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://wordpressdev.burnnotice.co.za'); return false;">info@taxleaders.net</a> in order to track the email.
Is there a way I can check if it is working? Sorry I have never tried this before so am a bit blank.

Comment: Yes you can check the google analytics reports from your GA account.

Comment: Once you get the links clicked , you can check all the records from GA reports section.

Comment: Are you there for a support on the same matter?

Answer (score 0):

@ragmah If you want to automatically do this, without touching JavaScript. Download this Wordpress Plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-tel-tracking

The plugin adds Google Tracking code to tel and mailto links. This is the [JavaScript](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/simple-tel-tracking/trunk/tracking-code.js) that it adds:

```
(function( jQuery ) {

    "use strict";

    // Telephone numbers
    jQuery("a[href^=tel]").each(function( index ) {
        var tel_number = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace('tel:', '').replace(';', '');
        stt_add_google_tracking_code(this, "Phone Call Tracking: " + tel_number);
    });

    // Mailto links
    jQuery("a[href^=mailto]").each(function( index ) {
        var email_address = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace('mailto:', '').replace(';', '');
        stt_add_google_tracking_code(this, "Mailto Tracking: " + email_address);
    });

    /**
     * Function to check if the [element] has an onclick handler,
     * if it does not! Then adds a google anayltics tracking code with
     * the tracking_string param as event.
     *
     * @param element         jquery element, e.g. <a href="tel" or <a href="mailto" 
     * @param tracking_string Event String
     */
    function stt_add_google_tracking_code(element, tracking_string) {
        if (jQuery( element ).attr('onclick') != undefined) {
            console.warn('Element already has something onclick, not setting Tracking code for the following element:');
            console.warn(element);
        }

        jQuery( element ).attr(
            'onclick',
            "ga('send', 'event','" + tracking_string + "','Click/Touch');"
        );
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Full code: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/simple-tel-tracking/trunk